# Calculate a value between two values with date references

Tags: php, datetime

Okay so this is what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to return a rough estimate of a temperature for a given dateTime object.

I know that:

- on 2016-05-19 09:00:00 the temperature was 4°C
- on 2016-05-19 12:00:00 the temperature was 8°C

I want to know an approximation of temperature for a given dateTime object between the ones shown above based on the two temperatures either side of the date range.

Haven't a clue where to start with this one so any help would be welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume a straight line between the two datapoints, then:

Gradient is

```
 g:=   (Temp2-Temp1) / (Time2-Time1)
```

This we assume is true for all (temperature,time) points.
If you want to find the temperature Temp3 at Time3

```
(Temp3-Temp1) / (Time3-Time1) = g

Temp3-Temp1 = (Time3-Time1) * g

Temp3 = Temp1 + (Time3-Time1) * g
```

Don't you kids learn algebra anymore? ;-)

(I wish I was able to format this like math)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @leif-netland answer the final working code example for reference is:

```
$time1 = (new dateTime())->format('YmdHis');
$temp1 = 4;

$time2 = (new dateTime())->modify('+2 hours')->format('YmdHis');
$temp2 = 8;

$time3 = (new dateTime())->modify('+1 hours')->format('YmdHis');

$gradient = ($temp1-$temp2) / ($time1 - $time2);

$temp3 = $temp1 + ($time3 - $time1) * $gradient; // 6
```